# How can I test file existence using regular expressions

Tags: powershell

I want to test if the file `C:\workspace\test_YYYYMMDD.txt`, where YYYYMMDD means year, month, and date, exists on my disk.

How can I do this in PowerShell?

I know that `test-path test_*.txt` command returns true.

But `test_*.txt` also returns true when the file name is something like *test_20170120asdf.txt*, or *test_2015cc1119aabb.txt*.

I don't want file names like *test_20170120asdf.txt* being marked as true in `test-path`.

I'd like to apply regular expression `test_\d{8}\.txt` in `test-path`. How can I do this in PowerShell?

Comment: If you know the name test-path is ok, but otherwise you'll have to iterate over a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
gci C:\workspace\test_*.txt | ? {$_.Name -match '^test_\d{8}\.txt$'}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Wildcard* expressions are much more limited in their matching abilities than *regular expressions* - see [`Get-Help about_Wildcards`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcard) - but in this particular case they're enough:

```
Test-Path test_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
```

If more sophisticated matching is needed, see [LotPing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754934/45375), which shows how to use *regular expressions*.